# How to make cart Totals (shipping and tax) display labels before address entered in and calculated?

Tags: checkout, shopping-cart, totals, ce-1.8.0.0

I am hoping to change some of the functionality and display for the shopping cart totals.  Ideally I would like them to display as follows when the customer first gets to the cart page before they enter their address.

- Subtotal: $435.99
- Shipping & Handling: ---
- Tax: ---
- Grand Total: ---

Currently when a customer goes to the cart, this is what they see.

- Subtotal: $435.99
- Grand Total: $435.99

Which is not ideal, as that is clearly not the actual "grand total" they will be paying.  Also if they use the Estimate Shipping and Tax to get a quote, It will add the Tax to the price, but it will just show and not add the shipping cost unless the customer actually clicks the radio button and clicks "update totals".  If the grand total is not shown until the customer clicks "Update totals" they will know that they have to do that to see the end price.

Any ideas How I can make this happen? Thanks

Comment: Does the "Estimate shipping & tax" block do what you need? It seems to match the functionality you are referring to. What version of Magento are you on?

Comment: We are on 1.8  -  It does the calculation properly, however it is not displayed well in the cart.  Will edit question with further explanation

Answer (score 2):

In the admin Panel go to System->configuration->Sales->Tax.
[image]

For shopping cart Display Settings follow as if in the image. You will get the answer as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a default shipping address to the "estimate shipping" block and calculate totals on page load. So customer will see the data, but can re-estimate for different address.